# What is the purpose of Contact Link in the Caldera forms activity processor?

Tags: wordpress, caldera-forms

I'm using the Activity Processor with Caldera forms.

At the bottom of the processor config page, there are three fields:

- Target Contact ID
- Source Contact ID
- Assignee Contact ID

Which make sense to me as ways to connect the activity to the other contacts in the form (or other contacts in CiviCRM).

But what is the purpose, if any, of the Contact Link field at the top of the page?

My best guesses are that either it is redundant and hard to remove, or that it serves some subtle purpose I am not aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Contact Link at the top of the page serves as a form of *labeling* **and** as a way to **connect/link** other entities (processors) like an Activity to a Contact on the form.

It's purpose may become redundant in the future, but just to be replaced with Caldera Forms' [magic tags](https://calderaforms.com/doc/using-magic-tags-caldera-forms/) (kinda like CiviMail tokens).

The link, and magic tags are a way to share and pass data/properties between processors or fields, they serve as a placeholder for later available data.

In Caldera Forms, the processors are processed/executed in the order they are added to the form (the order you see them in the Processor tab, from top to bottom).

A processor has three stages of processing:

1. `pre_processor`
2. `processor`
3. `post_processor`

*Most* processors in Caldera Forms CiviCRM do their *tasks* at `pre_processor` stage, and store their data in a transient object, the Contact processor would create a contact in CiviCRM and store it's result referenced by it's Contact Link so when the Activity processor is *processed* grabs it's necessary data from the *Linked Contact*.

Hope that gives a better picture on the Contact Link's purpose :)